# pin the first row when viewing a data table with a bash program such as less

Tags: bash

I have a space-delimited file `data.txt` that I am reading with less:

```
less -S data.txt
```

I want the first row to stay pinned to the top of the terminal.

Is there a way to accomplish this in bash? It doesn't need to be using `less`, and it's fine if it requires defining a new bash function or alias.

Comment: `bash` doesn't have any features that can be used to create a less-like application that operates like this. You'd basically have to write your own application, or modify `less` itself to add it. The latter would probably be easiest.

Comment: `less` isn't a "bash program", it's just a program -- an executable like any other. You can use it without bash (or any other shell) even installed at all. Except to the extent of wiring up file descriptors before executing a child process, the shell doesn't control how programs it starts interact with the terminal; a program running in the foreground takes full control over the file descriptors used for interacting with the TTY, so the shell is completely out of the loop and can't modify that behavior once the program is started.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes use Vim as a pager:

```
command | vim -
```

In Vim you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> to split the screen vertically.

This has an annoying default to split the screen in half. You can give it a numeric prefix like <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> to make the top split one line tall.

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd>, or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to toggle between the splits.

This is all inconvenient to fiddle with manually each time you want a pager with a one-line split. Here is how to do it in a single command:

```
command | vi -c '1split | winc w' -
```

The `-c` tells Vim to run two commands after opening the file. The first one `1split` creates a one line split at the top of the screen. The `:winc w` is the colon command way to execute a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> to switch the cursor to the bottom split, so you're ready to scroll the main view.

Make an alias for the `vi ...` part like

```
alias vl='vi -c "1split | winc w" -'
```

and then it's easy to use as `command | vl`.

Comment: BTW, `command` is the name of [a specific built-in command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html#tag_20_22), so it's not a great placeholder; I typically use `yourcommand` or `somecommand` or such.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's true. It's a POSIX-specified utility which provides access to a real command, useful when we write wrapper functions for commands that must run a real one. It don't think it's huge issue.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I tried `command | less` and it works fine in my environment. `command` produced no output and succeeded; `less` captured the empty output. So actually, it's a fine meta-command for this usage; it will behave meaningfully if taken literally.